# IndexOutOfRangeException in ConditionalWeakTable.GetOrCreateValue()

Tags: c#, .net

I am using [`ConditionalWeakTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757(v=vs.110).aspx) as part of a weak event handler implementation. It works fine, except occasionally I get automatic crash logs from my users indicating that a call to `GetOrCreateValue()` has crashed.

The error and call stack looks like one of the following two stacks, I assume depending on whether there's an existing entry or a new one needs to get created:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable`2.CreateEntry(TKey key, TValue value)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable`2.GetValue(TKey key, CreateValueCallback createValueCallback)
   at [my code]

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable`2.TryGetValueWorker(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable`2.GetValue(TKey key, CreateValueCallback createValueCallback)
   at [my code]
```

(The actual call to `GetOrCreateValue()` appears to have been inlined.)

Here's my code that declares the `ConditionalWeakTable`:

```
private static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<object, Dictionary<EventInfo, object>> s_sourceObjects = new ConditionalWeakTable<object, Dictionary<EventInfo, object>>();
```

Here's my code that calls `GetOrCreateValue()`:

```
Dictionary<EventInfo, object> events;
lock(s_sourceObjects)
    events = s_sourceObjects.GetOrCreateValue(sourceObject);
```

And here's the only other place that references the `s_sourceObjects` field:

```
bool success;
Dictionary<EventInfo, object> events;
lock(s_sourceObjects)
    success = s_sourceObjects.TryGetValue(sourceObject, out events);
```

(I added the `lock` statements because I suspected there was a thread-safety bug in `ConditionalWeakTable` despite the documentation claiming it's thread-safe. However, the bug still occurs even with the `lock` statements, so apparently it's not a threading issue.)

My application uses .NET 4.6.2.

Am I somehow misusing or not understanding `ConditionalWeakTable`? Or is this a framework bug? If it's a framework bug, is there any way I can work around it?

Here's the entire source code for the class, if anyone wants to see the context: https://gist.github.com/waltdestler/2a339bdd0d7d647501eb4690772e3b50

Comment: Are they the **only** two places you access `ConditionalWeakTable`?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, those are the **only** two places (in additional to the field initializer).

Comment: That exception is more likely to be related to the `s_staticEvents` to be honest. Are you running in `Debug` or `Release` mode?

Comment: @mjwills This is `Release`. The parts that I cut out of the stack trace indicate that the exception happens inside my `Subscribe` method, not `SubscribeStatic`, so unless the stack trace itself is horribly wrong, I'm pretty sure it's a problem with `s_sourceObjects`. (I ship the PDB files with my application, and even the line number in the stack trace matches exactly. Plus, all accesses of `s_staticEvents` are `lock`ed.)

Comment: Can you test it in `Debug`, and also include the full stack trace?

Comment: Unfortunately I've never been able to reproduce this locally. I'd have to send a `Debug` build to my users and wait for the errors.

Comment: @mjwills Just in case you're curious, it turned out to be an external tool that was editing memory values and causing the crash. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is having this problem, I want to follow-up with what turned out to be the problem:

My program is actually a video game, and it turns out that some players were using a tool called Cheat Engine which can be used to directly modify memory values. (For example, changing the memory that holds how much money the player has.) I've discovered that Cheat Engine is running whenever this crash occurs, which leads me to believe that players are trying to use it to cheat in the game and are inadvertently editing the wrong memory location and causing it to crash.